# Filter a stream of a class using a value of subclass

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a parent class `Company` which has a list of `Employee` objects. I need to create a stream of `Parent` class who has an `Employee` with the phone number mentioned.

```
Company cmp1 = new Company();
cmp1.setName("oracle");

Company cmp2 = new Company();
cmp1.setName("Google");

Employee emp1 = new Employee();
emp1.setName("David");
emp1.setPhone("900");
Employee emp2 = new Employee();
emp2.setName("George");
emp2.setPhone("800");
Employee emp4 = new Employee();
emp4.setName("BOB");
emp4.setPhone("300");
Employee emp5 = new Employee();
emp5.setName("taylor");
emp5.setPhone("900");

List<Employee> cmp1EmpList1 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
cmp1EmpList1.add(emp1);
cmp1EmpList1.add(emp2);
cmp1.setEmployees(cmp1EmpList1);

List<Employee> cmp1EmpList2 = new ArrayList<Employee>();
cmp1EmpList2.add(emp4);
cmp1EmpList2.add(emp5);

cmp2.setEmployees(cmp1EmpList2);

List<Company> companies = Arrays.asList(cmp1, cmp2);
```

To retrieve the stream I have tried adding the below code

```
List<Company> companiesWithEmployeesphone800 = companies.stream()
    .filter(loc -> loc.getEmployees()
                    .stream()
                    .flatMap(locnew -> locnew.getPhone()
                                        .equalsIgnoreCase("800"))
            )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but received incompatible types.

Answer (score 3):

Use `anyMatch` for a predicate instead of `flatMap` as:

```
List<Company> companiesWithEmployeesphone800 =
    companies.stream()
            .filter(loc -> loc.getEmployees().stream()
                    .anyMatch(locnew -> locnew.getPhone().equalsIgnoreCase("800")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Since case sensitivity is quiet irrelevant for a string like `"800"`, a plain `equals` will do as well…